# Paint for Gas Stove

Tags: paint, stove

The photo shows an older gas stove that is chipped (black spots).  Is there a good paint (preferably from Home Depot or Lowe's) that should be used for this type hot environment?

## UDPATE:

This stove is for a rental unit and this tenant is really tough on gear.  They pay for repairs, but a sensible approach would take this into account

[image]

Comment: The original surface is baked-on ceramic. It's tough to replicate that with anything like the same durability. The best bet may be to ship it to a ceramic shop. Or hit Craigslist for a new range.

Comment: Trouble maintaining tenant-grade stoves often starts with the stove being cheaply made to begin with.  A fact which lands in the landlord's lap.). The upshot is trying to fix it may be "good money after bad".  The fact that you want a big-box store solution echoes the "cheap factor" (but big-box is in fact overpriced, and does not offer the better and more dangerous tiers of products.) Your path here is new top or a new stove, or present a rinky dink repair to the next client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most home centers have porcelain chip repair products. Sheffield and Rustoleum are a couple of popular brands. It is supplied in a small bottle with a brush built into the cap similar to automotive touch-up paint. It will cover the chip and prevent the steel from rusting. The repair will be visible, but less obvious.